How to remove system extension on 14.4.1
$ systemextensionsctl list
1 extension(s)
--- com.apple.system_extension.network_extension
enabled active  teamID  bundleID (version)  name    [state]
*   *   DE8Y96K9QP  com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext (4.10.04065/4.10.04065)    Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter Extension    [activated enabled]
Antons-MacBook-Air:MacOS agraph$ systemextensionsctl uninstall DE8Y96K9QP com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext
At this time, this tool cannot be used if System Integrity Protection is enabled.
This limitation will be removed in the near future.
Please remember to re-enable System Integrity Protection!

It seems that SIP should be glad that there is one less extension on the system?
How could I get rid of the CISCO remnants I no longer need lying(running) around the mac?
Not sure how it got onto the system with SIP enabled.

I’m guessing you upgraded a Mac with this installed previously? I’m also guessing you can’t install the software and then run the latest uninstaller? My bookmarks have this, but I’m not sure I can reproduce or test something anytime soon, so I’ll comment only with potentially helpful links.

Yes, I have installed Sonoma after AnyTime Connect was already on the previous macos version.
